# Email sent through CakeEmail showing attachments icon in outlook even when no attachments is sent

Tags: php, email, cakephp, outlook, cakeemail

I have using CakeEmail to send email but when I send Html and text email  then the email show the attachment icon in the outlook .

I found that it is because of header Content-type: multipart/mixed; .

But it should be Content-Type:multipart/aternative;

I tried to override it by using $Email->setHeaders();

But it didn't changed.

Please suggest how do I change the Content-Type header in CakeEmail.

Comment: See [the cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html), did you set `emailFormat` to `both`?

Comment: Have you tested that using `multipart/alternative` actually fixes the problem? (you can do so by overriding [**`CakeEmail::getHeaders()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.7/lib/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php#L752-L753)). In that case you might want to report this via the [**issue tracker**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues). ps. Please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: yes emailFormat set to 'both'